# JSON array to ExpandoObject via JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, expandoobject

I am using the following approach to convert most of my API JSON results into an object:

```
public void ExpandoObject()
{
    var sampleDATA = Sample.Create();
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sampleDATA);

    var expConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, expConverter);

    var a = obj.A;

    var b = obj.B;

    var c = obj.C; //and so on...
}
```

However, I run into a strange situation with this format of JSON...

```
[
    {
        "id": 42,
        "name": "example name",
        "member_count": 42,
        "created_date": "example created_date",
        "last_update": "example last_update",
        "last_reset": "example last_reset"
    }
]
```

Because it is an array, how can I access the items, the ExpandoObject is supposed to be an IDictionary of sorts.

Anyone had experience with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `List<ExpandoObject>` when deserializing:

```
var expConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(json, expConverter);
```

Your `obj` variable will be list of expando objects that you can iterate.

Comment: What is `expConverter`. What does it do?

Comment: It is `ExpandoObjectConverter`. I missed it when posting the answer. It is edited now.