# Get the values of dynamic keys from a JSON string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this json string and i want to get the 4th line `(iValue, sValue)` of every record.
My problem here is the keys vary for every record (based on the data type of the value).

Is there any way to do this on C#?

Here is an example:

```
{ "data": [
        {
          "pKey": "0",
          "Entity": "tableName",
          "Attribute": "CID",
          "iValue": "13"
        },
        {
          "pKey": "0",
          "Entity": "tableName",
          "Attribute": "username",
          "sValue": "test_user1"
        }] }
```

Comment: Does every record only have `iValue` or `sValue`, or are there other possible keys?

Comment: According to the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/), a JSON object is *an **unordered** set of name/value pairs.*  So, do you really want the 4th value in each `"data"` object no matter which value it is?  Or do you want the value named `"iValue"` no matter which whether it appears 4th?

Comment: `sValue` for String, `iValue` for integer, `pValue` for decimal, `fValue` for float, `dValue` for date and/or time, `bValue` for binary/varbinary respectively.

Comment: Right - the question should state that then. So you have a fixed set of possible keys, but more than the ones you've shown. You'll need to extend the ideas given in the answers so far to include the extra keys, but then it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: @JoshuaPena if you want to impose a schema, use JSON Schema. JSON doesn't have decimals, floats, dates etc. and using prefixes is a *very* bad idea. JSON doesn't need an attribute/value structure either -
 objects *are* dictionaries.  Why use this form instead of `"myEntity" : { "Key":0", "CID":13, "username","test_user1"}`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This JSON is converted from a generated XML from a Web Service that I do not have any control of. What I am just trying to do is get the `[i/s]Value` of the `"data"'s` 4th line to complete my code.

Comment: @JoshuaPena XML doesn't need this either. Why convert to JSon though instead of deserializing the XML content? JSON isn't going to make this easier. In any case, you'll have to either 1) add multiple properties, one for each name, or 2) retrieve the objects as JObject instances and check the attribute names. #1 is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is kind of a big implementation, you will have to implement this for each `iValue`, `fValue`, etc however, it speeds up the implementation and usage. First of, here is the usage:

```
string rawJson = "{\"data\":[{\"pKey\":\"0\",\"Entity\":\"tableName\",\"Attribute\":\"CID\",\"iValue\":\"13\"},{\"pKey\":\"0\",\"Entity\":\"tableName\",\"Attribute\":\"username\",\"sValue\":\"test_user1\"}]}";

var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TakeData>(rawJson).Data.Select(v => v.PureData);
```

Now `values` contains the list. Here is the usage for accessing each:

```
foreach (var val in values)
{
    if (val is IntData i)
    {
        int myInt = i.iValue;
        // use the rest of the properties
    }
    else if (val is StrData s)
    {
        string myStr = s.sValue;
        // use the rest of the properties
    }
}
```

And here is the implementation:

```
class TakeData
{
    public List<TakeItAll> Data { get; set; }
}

class TakeItAll
{

    public int pKey { get; set; }
    public string Entity { get; set; }
    public string Attribute { get; set; }

    private int _iValue;
    public int iValue
    {
        get => _iValue;
        set
        {
            _iValue = value;
            PureData = new IntData { pKey = pKey, Entity = Entity, Attribute = Attribute, iValue = iValue };
        }
    }

    private string _sValue;
    public string sValue
    {
        get => _sValue;
        set
        {
            _sValue = value;
            PureData = new StrData { pKey = pKey, Entity = Entity, Attribute = Attribute, sValue = sValue };
        }
    }

    public IPureData PureData { get; private set; }

}

interface IPureData
{
    int pKey { get; set; }
    string Entity { get; set; }
    string Attribute { get; set; }
}

class IntData : IPureData
{
    public int pKey { get; set; }
    public string Entity { get; set; }
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    public int iValue { get; set; }
}

class StrData : IPureData
{
    public int pKey { get; set; }
    public string Entity { get; set; }
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    public string sValue { get; set; }
}
```

Of course you can use some alternatives as well. Such as using an enum in `TakeItAll` to keep track of the data type (or a type variable) instead of so many classes. This way  However the size of the `values` object would be larger.

```
class TakeItAll
{

    public int pKey { get; set; }
    public string Entity { get; set; }
    public string Attribute { get; set; }

    private int _iValue;
    public int iValue
    {
        get => _iValue;
        set
        {
            _iValue = value;
            ValType = typeof(string);
        }
    }

    private string _sValue;
    public string sValue
    {
        get => _sValue;
        set
        {
            _sValue = value;
            ValType = typeof(int);
        }
    }

    public Type ValType { get; private set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would deserialize this into an object supporting both types of properties and then by code try parsing either the integer or the string if the integer fails.

If the `Attribute` value gives you a clue as to which one to look for, you could also use that to prevent having to try parsing the integer every time.

I would not rely on the property being the "fourth" property every time, as I'm assuming this would be external data, where you may not be able to control whether these properties come out in the exact same order every time (now and in the future).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't know the data type then you could use an object to handle it.
2. It's a good idea to deserialize JSON string to concrete class to avoid string manipulation mistake.

   ```
   public class Datum
   {
       public object pKey { get; set; }
       public string Entity { get; set; }
       public string Attribute { get; set; }
       public string iValue { get; set; }
       public string sValue { get; set; }
   }

   public class DataCollection
   {
       public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
   }

   public void Test()
   {
       var str = "{\"data\":[{\"pKey\":\"0\",\"Entity\":\"tableName\",\"Attribute\":\"CID\",\"iValue\":\"13\"},{\"pKey\":\"0\",\"Entity\":\"tableName\",\"Attribute\":\"username\",\"sValue\":\"test_user1\"}]}";
       var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataCollection>(str);
       var keys = list.data.Select(x => x.pKey).ToList();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to deserialize to `dynamic` and inspect that:

```
var json = "{\"data\":[{\"pKey\":\"0\",\"Entity\":\"tableName\",\"Attribute\":\"CID\",\"iValue\":\"13\"},{\"pKey\":\"0\",\"Entity\":\"tableName\",\"Attribute\":\"username\",\"sValue\":\"test_user1\"}]}";

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType<dynamic>(json, null);

if (result.data != null)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.Count; i++)
    {
        if (result.data[i]["iValue"] != null)
            // Parse iValue
        if (result.data[i]["sValue"] != null)
            // Parse sValue

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load the Json in a ExpandoObject

```
var expConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic objList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(json, expConverter);
```

[JSON array to ExpandoObject via JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464751/json-array-to-expandoobject-via-json-net)

Then once you have loaded it in as a `List<ExpandoObject>` you may itterate over it as a dictionary.

```
    foreach(var obj in objList) 
    {
//convert the object to a Dictionary and select the 4th element.
      var yourresult = (obj as IDictionary<string, object>).ElementAt(3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

### Get each object of the array as a `KeyValuePair`

```
var json = "your json here";

var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

foreach (var element in root.Data)
{
    //===================================================> Here using object because your value type change. You can change it to string if your value is always wrapped in a string (like "13")
    var keyValuePair = element.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    //here, for each object of the 'data' array, you can check if the desidered property exists
    if (keyValuePair.ContainsKey("iValue"))
    {
        var propertyValue = keyValuePair["iValue"];
    }
    else if (keyValuePair.ContainsKey("sValue"))
    {
        var propertyValue = keyValuePair["sValue"];
    }

    // Or you can check the property name in the desidered position
    if (keyValuePair.Keys.ElementAt(3) == "iValue")
    {
        var propertyValue = keyValuePair["iValue"];
    }
    else if (keyValuePair.Keys.ElementAt(3) == "sValue")
    {
        var propertyValue = keyValuePair["sValue"];
    }
}
```

Where `Root` is

```
class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<JObject> Data { get; set; }
}
```

With this solution you can always know which property (`iValue` or `sValue`) is specified. On the contrary, if you use a model class which has both property names, you wouldn't know which property is specified when the value is `null` (unless you use additional properties/classes and a custom `JsonConverter`).

### Edit

As [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) reminded me, the `JObject` class implements `IDictionary<string, JToken>`. So, inside your `foreach` you could use:

```
if (element["iValue"] != null)
{
    var propertyValue = element["iValue"].Value<string>();
}
if (element["sValue"] != null)
{
    var propertyValue = element["sValue"].Value<string>();
}

// Or you can check the property name in the desidered position
var propName = element.Properties().ElementAt(3).Name;

if (propName == "iValue")
{
    var propertyValue = keyValuePair["iValue"].Value<string>();
}
else if (propName == "sValue")
{
    var propertyValue = keyValuePair["sValue"].Value<string>();
}
```

Of course you can optimize this code and check for nulls.

Comment: JSON objects *are* dictionaries. There's no need to deserialize [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) to a Dictionary, it implements `IDictionary<string, JToken>`

Comment: You are right @PanagiotisKanavos. Answer updated. Thank you.